# Prevent multiple threads from altering the same object

Tags: java, concurrency

I am currently implementing an Audit functionality for my application. I have developed an Audit Util (code cannot be attached). Here is what it does -

My application listens for events. When the events are posted to the designated Topic, my application listens to it and executes the `receiveAndDelegate()` method for Listener. Listener then delegates the control to one of the various Handler based on the Event ID by calling the appropriate Handler class's `handleMessage()` method.

What I do here is, as soon as the application listens to the event and calls the `receiveAndDelegate()` method of the listener, I am initializing the Audit object and capturing various message/logs as the control flows through the Listener class. Whenever Listener class delegates the control to the appropriate Handler class (by calling the appropriate handler class's `handleMessage()` method), I call a different Handler class's method, right before a call to the Handler class's `handleMessage()`, called `extractAndTransform()` and pass the audit object of the Listener class to this method. Within every handler class's `extractAndTransform()` method, I am creating a new audit object then initializing it using the audit object of the Listener class.

But here is the problem. Various threads are calling the listeners at the same time and the audit objects that are getting passed between the different calls from Listener classes to the Handler classes are getting overwritten with the subsequent calls. Let us say that a request REQ1 is received and calls the Listener class, then audit is initialized respective to this event. So throughout the process, this audit object should have the logs corresponding to the REQ1 but it is not so. It is capturing the logs for other requests as well and everything is getting hodge-podge.

**A brief class structure**

```
@Component
public class MessageListener {
    @Autowired
    private AuditUtil audit;

    public receiverAndDelegate(Object message) {
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        IHandler handler = <logic to get the handler for the event>

        handler.extractAndTransform(audit, (FBBEvent) message);

        handler.handleMessage((FBBEvent) message);
    }
}


public interface IHandler {
    public extractAndTransform(AuditUtil audit, FBBEvent fbbEvent);
    public handlerMessage(FBBEvent fbbEvent);
}

@Component 
public class SomeHandler implements IHandler {
    @Autowired
    private AuditUtil audit;

    public extractAndTransform(AuditUtil audit, FBBEvent fbbEvent) {
        this.audit = someMethodToExtactValuesAndCreateANewAuditObject(audit, fbbEvent);
    }

    public handleMessage(FBBEvent fbbEvent) {
        audit.logEvent("Enetered the method handleMessage");

        try {
            Connection con = <getting a new connection>();
            
            audit.logEvent("Created connection successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            audit.logEvent("Exception while creating connection" + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to address this are:

- Synchronize handler using as mutex, to ensure that only a single handler instance can be executed at a time.
- Use a queue to decouple MessageListener from the handler.

The first approach is an easy way to introduce correctness into your application at the expense of throughput which will cause an increase in latency:

```
@Component
public class MessageListener {
    @Autowired
    private AuditUtil audit;

    public receiverAndDelegate(Object message) {
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        IHandler handler = <logic to get the handler for the event>

       
        mutex.lock()
        try {
          handler.extractAndTransform(audit, (FBBEvent) message);

          handler.handleMessage((FBBEvent) message);
        } finally {
          mutex.unlock()
        }
    }
}
```

This ensures that there are no overlapping message handlers. Your program is "correct" now assuming that overlapping message handlers are invalid for your particular program.

The problem here is that receiverAndDelegate executes in serial, it's only able to handle a single message at a time!!!!

One solution for this is to use an [actor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) and have a message topic/queue per handler type. Each message topic or queue could have a single handler consumer, which:

- pulls a message
- calls `extractAndTransform`
- calls `handleMessage`

Because you have a single handler it ensure that there will never be 2 concurrent handlers of the same type executing. It also maximizes the `receiverAndDelegate` throughput. The `MessageListener` only has to inspect the handler type and publish the message to that specific handlers input queue.

Comment: Both of the above solutions are not possible. This is a very critical application and latency is not tolerated. Also, queue/topic have already been implemented, cannot change that as well. Have one queue and topic (FBB Queue/FBB Topic) and every message posted to this topic calls the same message Listener (FBBPortalMessageListener). Any other solution?